# Jolt - Flatten JSON array

Tags: java, json, jolt

***Input***:

```json
{
  "creatives": [
    {
      "link_promo": [
        "https://facebook.com/123",
        "https://facebook.com/456"
      ]
    },
    {
      "link_promo": [
        "https://facebook.com/789",
        "https://facebook.com/101112"
      ]
    },
    {
      "link_promo": [
        "https://facebook.com/121314",
        "https://facebook.com/141516"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Spec**:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "creatives": {
        "*": {
          "link_promo": "promo_links[]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Output**:

```json
{
  "promo_links": [
    [
      "https://facebook.com/123",
      "https://facebook.com/456"
    ],
    [
      "https://facebook.com/789",
      "https://facebook.com/101112"
    ],
    [
      "https://facebook.com/121314",
      "https://facebook.com/141516"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Desired Output:

```json
{
  "promo_links": [
    "https://facebook.com/123",
    "https://facebook.com/456",
    "https://facebook.com/789",
    "https://facebook.com/101112",
    "https://facebook.com/121314",
    "https://facebook.com/141516"
  ]
}
```

Hi guys, i need to flatten nested list to an array as description above.
Hi guys, i need to flatten nested list to an array as description above.
Any ideas how to modify my jolt spec to achieve that output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just nest one more step by replacing the part

`"link_promo": "promo_links[]"` with `"link_promo": { "*": "promo_links" }`

in order to reach innermost part of the JSON as in the following spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "creatives": {
        "*": {
          "link_promo": {
            "*": "promo_links"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/

[image]

Comment: tysm sir, u've saved my time

Comment: you're welcome @TienPhamVan , nice to help